# Simulating mouse clicks in World of Warcraft with python, but in background to specific coordinates

Tags: python, mouseevent, background-process, world-of-warcraft, minimized

I am trying to simulate right mouse click to WoW, I managed to send keyboard presses and the mouse click to minimized window without activating it, but for the mouse clicks it just doesn't click where I want. If I do it in activated window the cursors position is 959, 519, but if I try it with

```
win32api.PostMessage(hwndMain, win32con.WM_RBUTTONDOWN, 0, 34014143)
```

or

```
win32api.PostMessage(hwndMain, win32con.WM_RBUTTONDOWN, 959, 519)
```

it just wont work, it does click only within WoW but it still uses the cursor real position.

I am fairly new to Python, would u know a solution?

Below whole code I use

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time
import random
from tkinter import *
import win32api
import win32con
from window_list import window_list

keyboard = Controller()
looping = 0
hwndMain = window_list["World of Warcraft"]

time.sleep(1)

def inter_attack():
    for key in range(6):    
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 0.7))
        
        win32api.PostMessage(hwndMain, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, 0x46, 0) 
        win32api.PostMessage(hwndMain, win32con.WM_KEYUP, 0x46, 0)

        time.sleep(random.uniform(2.5, 3.5))
        
        win32api.PostMessage(hwndMain, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, 0x32, 0) 
        win32api.PostMessage(hwndMain, win32con.WM_KEYUP, 0x32, 0)
       
#infinite loop
while looping == 0:     
    #time.sleep(1) 
    #win32api.SetCursorPos((959, 519)) # just to find if coordinates work and where to put the mouse click
    time.sleep(0.1)
   
    win32api.PostMessage(hwndMain, win32con.WM_RBUTTONDOWN, 0, 34014143)  
    win32api.PostMessage(hwndMain, win32con.WM_RBUTTONUP, 0, 34014143)

    time.sleep(1.5)   
    
    win32api.PostMessage(hwndMain, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, 0x35, 0) 
    win32api.PostMessage(hwndMain, win32con.WM_KEYUP, 0x35, 0)

    inter_attack()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the keyboard and mouse modules - I'm sure `win32api` is more powerful, but `keyboard` and `mouse` are simpler.

```
pip install keyboard
pip install mouse
```

You can check out the docs for more info, but you can do `keyboard.send('w')` for example.

For `mouse`, it's `mouse.click('right')`.

The reason you can't get the mouse to click at the right coordinates is because, for some reason, simulating mouse movements goes for position on the screen. Therefore, it's not a drag since the game centers the mouse. (It doesn't have a movement input, it just teleports the mouse.)

Comment: That would defeat the purpose as it means, it would not work in background, I intend to do work on my PC while this works in the back.

Comment: Oh - that's much harder. You'd need to find a way to specify the window for mouse activity.